# How to upgrade Debian 5 to Debian 9

Tags: debian, upgrade

I inherited a Debian 5 VM on a XEN host that I have to upgrade to Debian 9 and transfer on a HyperV host.

The VM is a Debian 5.0.5 with a 2.6.32-5-686-bigmem kernel.

Apache is version 2.2.9

PHP is version 5.2.6-1+lenny8

MySQL is version 5.0.51a

What is the least painful way to do the upgrade since it is not supported anymore ?

Thank you.

Comment: Upgrade kernel, glibc and the rest.

Comment: Totally agree with @IporSircer, upgrade first the system, then the app stack, then the rest. APT dependencies will do the job.

Comment: Would it be possible to launch a Debian 9 VM on the HyperV host? May be less painful as while it may be possible to upgrade from 5 to 9 there would be less outage.